# Can coating tungsten to stop oxidation?

Tags: metals

A patent that I read that stated:

"  Coating tungsten with nickel then with aluminum, will stop oxidation in open air environments. And even pass the melting points of both the tungsten and nickel, the metals doesn't seem to melt"

Will this hold up in a real engineering application, even if it goes past the melting points of nickel and aluminum?

Heres the patent: 
https://www.google.com/patents/US2682101

Comment: I don't find that phrase in that patent. I don't doubt the benefits of the coating, but at 6200F all that stuff will be gone in a hurry.